# bat file echos multiple lines

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-10, echo, command-prompt

i am trying to create a script to get some code from pastebin or something like that but i ran in to a problem with @echo off at the beginning of the file(is doesn't matter if the rest of the file work for now but the problem with echo is realy irritating)

my code is this

```
@Echo off

set bin=http://www.pastebin.com/raw/%1

set nam=%1.bat

bitsadmin /transfer myJob /download /priority normal %bin% %nam%

start %nam%

del %nam%

pause
```

and the output is

```
offset bin=http://www.pastebin.com/raw/%1set nam=%1.batbitsadmin /transfer myJob /download /priority normal  start del pause
```

for some reason (i used both notepad and notepad++ rot if it is like that nppp inserts weird newline characters of something but other code does work...)

but

```
@echo off

set hoi=rgrgae 

REM keymash

Echo %hoi%

pause
```

does work?

it might be just some obvious thing that i missed if so sorry

Comment: Perhaps you should make sure your batch file is using Windows`CRLF` line endings as opposed to MAC's `CR` style. As a side note, you should be using `Call` with `%nam%` not `Start`.

Comment: @Compo how do i change the line endings??

Comment: @adzwemer, you said you used Notepad++.  Surprised you have never seen that option.  It also has the ability to show you the line endings while editing the file.

Comment: I believe that the latest version of `notepad` in `Windows 10`, supports different `EOL` endings if the text containing them is pasted into it, _(subject to the registry not being altered to prevent it)_. So my advice is dont paste text into `notepad` if using the latest version in `Windows 10`, and if you don't know what line ending it is using, _(if you choose `View`>`Status Bar`, it may indicate the line ending when pasted)_. To change the line endings in `NotePad++`, I'd also assume that the option is available in the `Menu`, probably `View`>`EOL Conversion`>`Windows Format`, or similar.